# Values is not appearing in Current active Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net (Windows Application)

I have one main form(Data entry form), i creating many form at run time.

Code for creating a multiple form at run time.

Button1 click

```
If IsNothing(frm) OrElse frm.IsDisposed Then
            newfrm = New frmEntry
    End If
newfrm.Show()
```

I have popup windows for selcting the value in the Data entry form.

Code for selcting the value from popup windows

Popup Window code

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
 frmEntry.txtbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()          
End If
```

The above popup window code is working for Data Entry Form, but it is not working for new forms (at run time)

When i select the value from popup windows means, it is appearing in frmentry textbox, not in newfrm textbox.

Popup windows selected value should appear in current active form.

What wrong in my code.

Need VB.Net Code Help

Answer (score 1):

If the form you open the popup from is what you need to change values in, have you considered passing a reference to the opening form to the popup when you open it?  So that you have direct access to the form that has the controls that will need updated?

This constructor in the popup window:

```
Private mOpeningForm As frmEntry
Public Sub New(OpeningForm As frmEntry)

    InitializeComponent()

    mOpeningForm = OpeningForm
End Sub
```

This modified to use the reference to the form sent to the popup form:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
 mOpeningForm.txtbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()          
End If
```

This in the form when the window is being created at runTime:

```
If IsNothing(mEntryForm) OrElse mEntryForm.IsDisposed Then
            mEntryForm= New frmEntry(me)
    End If
mEntryForm.Show()
```

At the top level of the Data Form Class (The one creating the popups)

```
private mEntryForm as frmEntry
```

That will allow you to have a reference to the Instance of frmEntry from anywhere in the data form class.  (Note that I changed the name of the popup form instance in for the button click event code too)

Comment: That tends to bomb with a NullReferenceException.  The reason the OP used frmEntry.

Comment: I guess I figured the instance of the form he had created was still in scope.  Of course, if its not it would generate a null reference... I thought he OP had overlooked that he used the type name instead of the form name.

Comment: Turns out that code is in another form, he left a comment on my answer.

Comment: Updated based on comments.  Hopefully, I am in the right ballpark now and better understand the issue.

Comment: @D.  Your Code is Working, but i cannot able to refer the popup windows in the Entryform. For Example Popwindows form name as "frmlist".  In the EntryForm, i menioned in button click like this frmlist.show(), but it is showing error as "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference".

Comment: Added additional information to the answer.  I assumed you only allow one of the popup windows as a time.

Comment: @D. How we know whether mopeningform is active or not, Because in code i am using like this if frmenty.textbox1.focused = false then mopeningform.textbox1.text = "some gird value" else frmentry.textbox1.text ="some grid value",  It is showing error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  How to solve this....

Comment: If IsNothing(mEntryForm) OrElse mEntryForm.IsDisposed Then
            
  Checks that mEntryForm is not nothing.  You should do the same for mOpeningForm.

Comment: @D What is the name of new form in your code is mopeningform or mentryform..?

Comment: mOpeningForm is a reference to the main form that opens your popup.  That should be defined on your popup window.  mEntryForm is a reference to the popup window (frmEntry) and should be defined on the main form